# Angular can't open page with direct url, running on Node.js Express server

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have an Angular 9 app, that is running on a Node.js server. When running it locally from IntelliJ, the routing is working fine. I can go directly to any page, by changing the url, like:

```
mywebsite.com/page
```

However, if I deploy the app, the routing brakes. If I open the website

```
mywebsite.com
```

I can go to all pages, if I use menu on the website, but if I directly go to any url directy, like

```
mywebsite.com/page
```

I get

```
Cannot GET /page
```

Why can't it load?

UPDATE:

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "uj-kezdolap-frontend": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css", "src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "baseHref": "/",
              "deployUrl": "/",
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "uj-kezdolap-frontend:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "uj-kezdolap-frontend:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "uj-kezdolap-frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css", "src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["tsconfig.app.json", "tsconfig.spec.json", "e2e/tsconfig.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "uj-kezdolap-frontend:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "uj-kezdolap-frontend:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "uj-kezdolap-frontend",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
    'use strict';
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser`enter code here`');
    const isReachable = require('is-reachable');
    const https = require('https');
    const querystring = require('querystring');

    app.set('trust proxy', 'loopback');

    app.use(
      bodyParser.json({
        limit: '50mb',
      })
    );

    app.use(
      bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false,
      })
    );

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,X-Auth-Token,X-Language');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
      next();
    });

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

/**
* Some irrelevant logic here, that I did not copy
*/

    const server = app.listen(8080, () => {
      const host = server.address().address;
      const port = server.address().port;

      console.log('Listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
    });
```

The app is running in a Docker container

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY node_modules node_modules/
COPY app.js ./
COPY dist/ public/

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Comment: You need to redirect those pages to the index.html, because those files do not exist, Angular is taking care of the routing.

Comment: you should put your web config here also in question. Problem seems to that both your backend and frondend are same place

Comment: @pc_coder I have added every config, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, so I have figured it out.

I needed to update my app.js with the following lines of code:

```
const path = require('path');

/**
* All other logic
*/

app.use('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});
```

And you need to replace public/index.html to whatever path you have to the index.html from you app.js

Answer (score 0):

You could try building your app with the following flags:

```
ng build --base-href /

ng build --bh /

ng build --prod --bh /
```

Those are just different ways to accomplish the same task, hope it helps you!